# way to delete uploaded images entries from restAPI localhost server with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

I have manage to upload images for analysis to my restAPI localhost server and it is full of training data, i am tryin to delete all entries but have an issue with this code:

```
def delete_all_person(self,prsID):
        host_url = "api/person/delete?"

        parameters = {'person-id':prsID}

        r = requests.delete(base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters),headers={'Authorization': self.auth_tok}, data=data).json()
        return r
prsID = [5] #delete entry with id number 5.
prsID = [0:] #delete all entries.

cViS.delete_all_person()
```

i get error

```
TypeError: delete_person() missing 1 required positional argument: 'prsID'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def delete_all_person(self,prsID):
    host_url = "api/person/delete?"

    parameters = {'person-id':prsID}

    r = requests.delete(base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters),headers={'Authorization': self.auth_tok}, data=data).json()
    return r


prsID = [0:] #delete all entries.
cViS.delete_all_person(prsID)
```

Comment: when i edit my code to this one i get error:
```
`TypeError: delete_all_person() missing 1 required positional argument: 'prsID'`
```
then i add prsID arg to function call: but i get
```
`NameError: name 'prsID' is not defined`
```

Comment: i edited my answer, your problem was calling the function delete_all_person(), you had need to pass the person's id.

Comment: i think i understand what i did wrong thank you, i managed to delete 1 entry at a time by adding id number to function argument call.
but i am trying to know how to delete all entries?!